# Why 3DR Power Module has two 5v and GND output

Tags: quadcopter, uav, ardupilot, multi-rotor

Why are there two 5V and GND output in 3DR Power module (https://www.instructables.com/id/Safetly-use-CLONE-APM-Power-Modules/)
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6OSp05Y5b8).

Can we power up an APM 2.8 with just one pair of 5V and GND from this module.

Also, I would be most grateful if someone could please provide me the detailed circuit diagram (with explanation) of this module for a better understanding of its working.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: @jsotola I have provided the image of the module and added the reference, please have a look. I hope now you would be able to help me with my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Dual power and ground pins are on the power module so that two other modules could be powered without having to  split the power cables.

Also, if the attached module draws significant current from the power module, then all of the power pins could be used to keep connector contacts from being overloaded.

As far as the schematic, you need to study the datasheet for the regulator chip that is used in the device.